# How to display item from a deeper nested JSON array

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to display one item from a nested array:

```
{
"results":[
{
    "info": {
        "first_name": "JOHN",
        "last_name": "DOE"
    }
}
]}
```

I have tried multiple things but cannot get it to work to **only** display "first_name".

What I've tried is:

```
<div ng-repeat="s in display.results">
        <p>
            {{s.info}}
        </p>
</div>
```

But that just goes horribly wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `s.info.first_name`?

Comment: Yep that was it. Feel pretty dumb right now how I have been overlooking that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to access the 'first_name' property

```
<div ng-repeat="s in display.results">
  <p>
    {{s.info.first_name}}
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I realized that. Had been looking everywhere but overlooked one element. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but typically this sort of question should just be closed as "typo/no longer reproducible/resolved in a way that won't help future visitors".